# Limit Pagination Numbers For Huge Databases

Tags: php, mysql, database, pagination, limit

I can't seem to find the answer anyway so guess I need to ask at least I did try google anyway I am making a group feature similar to the one facebook has got but not as good since i'm the only one developing this but over time it get better.

Anyway,
how can I make this code limit the pagination numbers? for example if there is loads of results in the database I only want to first 10 to be displayed after that use dots so they can click and go more in depth if they want to so when the click the dot they get another 10 results so 20-30 will then be displayed as pagination. I don't need it exactly like this but some way to limit the ammount of numbers being displayed at a time.

Here;s the code

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<style type="text/css">
#content
{
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.page
{
float: right;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
.page li
{
    list-style: none;
    display:inline-block;
}
.page li a, .current
{
display: block;
padding: 5px;
text-decoration: none;
color: #8A8A8A;
}
.current
{
    font-weight:bold;
    color: #000;
}
.button
{
padding: 5px 15px;
text-decoration: none;
background: #333;
color: #F3F3F3;
font-size: 13PX;
border-radius: 2PX;
margin: 0 4PX;
display: block;
float: left;
}
</style>


</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
<?php
error_reporting(0);
$query1=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("freeze_demo",$query1);
error_reporting(0);
$start=0;
$limit=1;

if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $id=$_GET['id'];
    $start=($id-1)*$limit;
}

$query=mysql_query("select * from pagination LIMIT $start, $limit");
echo "<ul>";
while($query2=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    echo "<li>".$query2['text1']."</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";


$rows=mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("select * from pagination"));
$total=ceil($rows/$limit);

if($id>1)
{
    echo "<a href='?id=".($id-1)."' class='button'>PREVIOUS</a>";
}
if($id!=$total)
{
    echo "<a href='?id=".($id+1)."' class='button'>NEXT</a>";
}

echo "<ul class='page'>";
        for($i=1;$i<=$total;$i++)
        {

            if($i==$id) { echo "<li class='current'>".$i."</li>"; }

            else { echo "<li><a href='?id=".$i."'>".$i."</a></li>"; }
        }
echo "</ul>";
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Just basically need to update it for the future when my database or a certain group gets bigger.

Thanks

Comment: it can be hard to explain the issue sometimes what I want to to display limit of the pagination numbers displayed at once it will get messy if you have 100 pagination numbers being displayed

Comment: fixed the sql error ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 
function custom_pagination($page, $totalpage, $link, $show)  //$link = '&page=%s' 
{ 
    //show page 
if($totalpage == 0) 
{ 
return 'Page 0 of 0'; 
} else { 
    $nav_page = '<div class="navpage"><span class="current">Page '.$page.' of '.$totalpage.': </span>'; 
    $limit_nav = 3; 
    $start = ($page - $limit_nav <= 0) ? 1 : $page - $limit_nav; 
    $end = $page + $limit_nav > $totalpage ? $totalpage : $page + $limit_nav; 
    if($page + $limit_nav >= $totalpage && $totalpage > $limit_nav * 2){ 
        $start = $totalpage - $limit_nav * 2; 
    } 
    if($start != 1){ //show first page 
        $nav_page .= '<span class="item"><a href="'.sprintf($link, 1).'"> [1] </a></span>'; 
    } 
    if($start > 2){ //add ... 
        $nav_page .= '<span class="current">...</span>'; 
    } 
    if($page > 5){ //add prev 
        $nav_page .= '<span class="item"><a href="'.sprintf($link, $page-5).'">&laquo;</a></span>'; 
    } 
    for($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i++){ 
        if($page == $i) 
            $nav_page .= '<span class="current">'.$i.'</span>'; 
        else 
            $nav_page .= '<span class="item"><a href="'.sprintf($link, $i).'"> ['.$i.'] </a></span>'; 
    } 
    if($page + 3 < $totalpage){ //add next 
        $nav_page .= '<span class="item"><a href="'.sprintf($link, $page+4).'">&raquo;</a></span>'; 
    } 
    if($end + 1 < $totalpage){ //add ... 
        $nav_page .= '<span class="current">...</span>'; 
    }     
    if($end != $totalpage) //show last page 
        $nav_page .= '<span class="item"><a href="'.sprintf($link, $totalpage).'"> ['.$totalpage.'] </a></span>'; 
    $nav_page .= '</div>'; 
    return $nav_page; 
} 
} 


//using
if(isset($_GET['page'])) {
    $page = $_GET['page'];
} else {
    $page = 1;
}
$sql = "SELECT count(*) AS total FROM post ORDER BY idpost DESC"; //please select COUNT is fast
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$rows = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$show = 5; //Show 5 result per page
$totalpage = ceil($rows['total'] / $show); //Total page
$start = ($page * $show) - $show; //Start result

$yourQuery = "SELECT * FROM post ORDER BY id LIMIT $start, $show";
//Query and show here

//Show pagination
echo custom_pagination($page, $totalpage, 'index.php?action=detail&page=%s', $show);

?>
```

Comment: Thanks so far :)
this code is outputing a sql array error but besides that it looks like it will work so hopefully you can look in to that but I try my best in fixing it

Answer (score 1):

Given that $id is a page number (perhaps refactor this to be $page so it it recognised as a page number, rather an a unique id of a particular record), you would change the final for loop to be a bit more restrictive.

For example, instead of starting at 1, start from 5 pages before the current page.  And instead of ending at `$total`, end at 5 pages after the current page.

```
$start = $id - 5.
if ($start < 1) {
    $start = 1;
}
$end = $id + 5;
if ($end > $total) {
    $end = $total;
}

for ($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i++) {
    // echo pagination options
}
```

You could also modify this to give links that will get you closer to where you want to go (i.e. if displaying pages 20 to 30, of 100 pages, show links for pages 10, 40, 50 and 60, or even supply an input box to let you jump to a specific page.

Comment: Thanks this is another great idea :D